# Android sound starter project for Eclipse

Tags: android, audio, beep

Is there an example Hello Sound project for Android that will show how to create beep sounds of a variable tone and duration?

Answer (score 0):

Try the API demos

Sound is in 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/index.html

The full list is

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Deploy the entire package to an emulator / phone to see what exactly is in the package. It's quite extensive.

Answer (score 0):

This project: http://code.google.com/p/chromadoze/ is a GREAT example of how to do some stuff with sound in Android.

Just create a clone: `svn checkout http://chromadoze.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ chromadoze-read-only`

and then import it in Eclipse.